# How to Match a string against patterns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a bit of different scenario. there is one column (Oracle table) in the table which stores patterns.another column with unique id.
Now, i have to match those patterns against a string and have to find out which patterns are matching that string.then i have to pick out those matched patterns along with the ids
Can anybody guide me on how to efficiently do it?

### Sample Data

```
Table 1
-------
Column1  Column2
1           AB%
2           A%
3           %c%
```

Now, there is a string comes like ABC (take it as an item number. It gets inserted in DB and then a trigger fires that has to do the rest of the job as provided in sample below)

```
Table 2
---------
Column1  Column2
ABC       AB%,A%
```

or more efficient(desired) Table 2 would be like -

```
  Table 2(desired)
    ---------
    Column1  Column2
    ABC       1,2
```

This is the desired result.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: Read about REGEXP_LIKE function. For example: AND regexp_like(col_name, '^[[:digit:]]+$')

Comment: If you just have to match in simpler way, why can't use Like clause Lol.:)

Comment: i have provided some sample data. Plz let me know if it clears the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 11g you could use function [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) 
and simple `before insert or update trigger`:

Sample data:

```
create table table1 (column1 number(3), column2 varchar2(10));
insert into table1 values (1, 'AB%');
insert into table1 values (2, 'A%');
insert into table1 values (3, '%c%');

create table table2 (column1 varchar2(10), column2 varchar2(500));
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tg_table2_ins
  before insert or update of column1 on table2 for each row 
declare  
  v_list table2.column2%type;
begin
  select listagg(t1.column1, ', ') within group (order by t1.column1) 
    into v_list from table1 t1
    where :new.column1 like t1.column2;

  :new.column2 := v_list;

end tg_table2_ins;
```

Test:

```
insert into table2 (column1) values ('ABC');
insert into table2 (column1) values ('Oracle');
insert into table2 (column1) values ('XYZ');
insert into table2 (column1) values ('Ascii');

select * from table2;

COLUMN1     COLUMN2
----------  ----------
ABC         1, 2
Oracle      3
XYZ
Ascii       2, 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.